# Styling Hooks tabs source

Tags: lightning-web-components, tab, winter21

Winter'21 made some changes on styling hooks for tabs and other items. Although, the hyperlink to show the availability of options in the lightning design system website does not exist anymore. Has anyone saved the list that could share? Not found either on previous summer'20 link.

> 2.13.0
> Added
> Enabled styling hooks for tab. See tab's styling hooks overview table for a full listing of the currently available hooks.

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tabs/#site-main-content

Answer (score 0):

Reached out to User Interface/User Experience team. They are currently working on this. Thanks for reporting

[image]

Comment: thanks Anudeep, will keep the post up to date when they add the info in the documentation.